# Jquery - Iterate all the comboboxes in the page and remove based on class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with multiple combo-boxes . Each combo-box has a default option as empty with class name 'hide'.
This works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Means,hidden options are not shown in Chrome and Firefox . But in IE and Safari , these are shown.

I want to write a jquery function to iterate all the combo-boxes in the page and remove the options with class name "hide".
How to achieve this?

```
<option value="-1" class="hide"></option>
```

Comment: With CSS `option.hide { display: none; }` With jQuery `$('option.hide').hide()` or to remove `$('option.hide').remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to achieve,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("option.hide").remove();
});
```